# scanf loop, and signal handler

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, signals, scanf

Just learned about sigacation, also implemented another timer to make it more interesting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h> 
#include <sys/time.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t gotsignal;


void handler(){

    gotsignal = 1;

}

int main(){

struct sigaction sig;
struct itimerval timer;

timer.it_value.tv_sec = 5;
timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
timer.it_interval = timer.it_value;

sig.sa_handler = handler; 
sig.sa_flags = 0; 
sigemptyset(&sig.sa_mask); 

setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, 0);
sigaction(SIGALRM, &sig, NULL);


int value, y = 100, x=0;

while(!gotsignal && x < y){
    printf("Insert a value: \n");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    x+=value;
    printf("Current x value: %d\n", x);
}
}
```

What i don't understand is, when it is waiting for user input and i write 5, but not press enter. He still reads it? Shouldn't he clear it off?
The output it gave me:

```
Insert a value: 
1
Current x value: 1
Insert a value: 
2
Current x value: 3
Insert a value: 
5Current x value: 5
```

What I would want would be like:

```
Insert a value: 
1
Current x value: 1
Insert a value: 
2
Current x value: 3
Insert a value: 
5(Wthout pressing enter!)Current x value: 3 (He would forget about 5 no?)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A (pedantically) correct [signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29) handler can do very few things: notably setting a `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable (this is some integer type), and perhaps calling `siglongjmp` [I'm not even sure for `siglongjmp`].

So declare first

```
volatile sig_atomic_t gotsignal;
```

then your signal handler is simply

```
void handler (void)
{
  gotsignal = 1;
}
```

and your loop is

```
while(!gotsignal && x < y){
    printf("Insert a value: \n");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    x+=value;
}
```

Don't forget that asynchronous **signals happen at any time** (any *machine* instruction!!!), including inside `malloc` or `printf`. Never call these functions from inside a handler.

**Bugs related to bad signal handling are hard to debug**: they are *not reproducible*!

Consider perhaps using [sigaction](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sigaction).

Comment: Hmmm. That makes sense. But what if I want the program to stop waiting for the scanf after the signal. For example, as soon as he gets the signal he would just forget about the scanf that he is waiting for and restart the loop normally. Is that possible?

Comment: I think that the `SIGALRM` signal will stop the `scanf`, since the `read` syscall (called by `scanf`)  would get an `EINTR` error. You might want to learn also about the `select`, `pselect` or `poll` (or `ppoll`) system calls. You can test if `scanf` failed by its returned value.

Comment: +1 for also suggesting `sigaction`, which unlike `signal`, is fully POSIX compliant.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Just edited the starting post, do you think you can still help me please?

Comment: Reading from the terminal is complex in the details, since it is a tty See http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal so you might want to use readline or ncurses libraries.